# Writing a loop with a step size 10, to print out all 2-digit numbers ending in 7 in increasing order in python

Tags: python, loops, digit

Write a program, using a for loop with step size 10, to print out all 2-digit numbers which end in 7, in increasing order

I have no idea where to start, or how to do this. help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

> `range(stop)`
>
> `range(start, stop[, step])`

```
>>> for n in range(17, 100, 10):
        print n

        
17
27
37
47
57
67
77
87
97
```